# How to detect test env during minitest runs (non rails project)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, tdd, bundler, minitest

When building a ruby application (such as a ruby gem)
I have a method, and it needs to "bail out" if "test env" is detected.

In a rails test, this is how I would do it

def foo
  return if Rails.env == "test"
end

How do you do it on a non-rails project. (I'm building a ruby gem with minitest as the test framework)

To give some background info, this project was started using instructions at http://bundler.io/v1.12/guides/creating_gem.html

```
bundle gem foodie
```

Comment: How are you defining "test env"? If using an environmental variable for example, you could do: `ENV["RACK_ENV"] == "test"`

Comment: Your question sounds a bit dubious to be, though. You shouldn't be polluting your main code base with logic like "skip this if running a test".... (Unless maybe you work for [Votswagen](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-34324772)!)

Comment: I would argue that a method that changes behavior in a test environment is untestable and that sounds like your method has design issues. Can you please explain what your method does and why you think it needs to change behavior in a test environment? Depending on your needs is mocking or stubbing the method in tests an option?

Comment: The reason I'm "bailing out" is because I call a library method called `run_instances()` and when it's run, my credit card is charged a fee by a service provider.